# Combinatorial Identity from $\textrm{sinc}(x)$ integrals

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, polyhedra

##### Setup

I've been reading/looking into variations on the $si(n) := \int_0^{\infty}\textrm{sinc}^n(x)$ for some power $n$ an integer, or the more general $si(a,b):= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^a(x)}{x^b}$ (a formula for $si(a,b)$ is provided on [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) of Wolfram Encyclopedia with a reference to an article that is lost to history, but see [[1]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00591-023-00342-5) of [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590849/192336) for a proof of this formula).

Anyway, solutions to $si(n)$ have been asked a number of times (e.g., [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307510/192336), [[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/347951/192336), [[5]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/378547/192336), and others I'm sure), but I was interested in the oft-pointed to paper [Some Remarkable Properties of Sinc
and Related Integrals by Borwein and Borwein](https://carmamaths.org/resources/db90/pdfs/db90-119.00.pdf), which uses Fourier transforms to derive the solution.

##### My Question: Combinatorial Identity in Borwein and Borwein

In the Borwein paper, they define the following in Section 3, Remarks 1c (I've simplified for my relevant question):
$$\gamma = (\gamma_1,\cdots,\gamma_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n,\quad \epsilon_{\gamma} = \prod_{i=1}^n\gamma_i,\quad b_{\gamma} = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma_i$$
They claim the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\gamma\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}, b_{\gamma}<0}\epsilon_{\gamma}b_{\gamma}^{n-1} = \sum_{1\leq r\leq \frac{n}{2}} (-1)^{r+1}\binom{n-1}{r-1}(n-2r)^{n-1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Equation (1) helps define the solution $si(n)$.

##### How to prove (1) (see edit)

Here's my short attempt so far:
Let's call $c_{\gamma}:=b_{\gamma}-1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\gamma_i<-1$ This only occurs when the number of $+1's$ in $\gamma$, called $s$ satisfies $0\leq s< \frac{n-1}{2}$. My combinatorics is weak, but pretty sure the number of $\gamma$ such that $c_{\gamma}=-k$ is something like $\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1-k}{2}}$. We can expand $b_{\gamma}^{n-1}$ using the binomial theorem:
$$
b_{\gamma}^{n-1} = \left(1+c_{\gamma}\right)^{n-1} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}c_{\gamma}^{n-1-j}\tag{2}
$$

I assume that I can just plug (2) back into (1) and do some simple algebra (while counting the number of ways for $b_{\gamma}$ or $c_{\gamma}$ to equal some value) but it appears not to be working, but I'll work more on it and edit if I make progress.

**Edit**:

So now I think I understand how to show this and I may answer my own question later when I have a chance to sit down and work this out. Counting the number of $\pm 1's$ is more complicated than this needs to be and is probably not going to help, instead reindex by the values of $b_{\gamma}$  which are in $\{2-n,4-n,\cdots,-2\textrm{ or } -1\}$. So we divide into cases when $b_{\gamma} = -(n-2r)$ for $1\leq r\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$. Then (1) becomes:
$$
\sum_{\gamma\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}, b_{\gamma}<0}\epsilon_{\gamma}b_{\gamma}^{n-1} = \sum_{1\leq r\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^{n-1}\epsilon_{\gamma}C_{\gamma}(n-2r)^{n-1}\tag{3}
$$

For $C_{\gamma}$ the number of binary vectors $\gamma$ such that $b_{\gamma} = -(n-2r)$. This now seems pretty simple: prove that $C_{\gamma} = \binom{n-1}{r-1}$, which is probably pretty easy, and $(-1)^{n-1}\epsilon_{\gamma} = (-1)^{r+1}$, which is also probably easy since it is equivalent to $\epsilon_{\gamma} = (-1)^{r+1 - (n -1)} = (-1)^{r-n}$, so there will be some manipulation here.

Comment: This is an history. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I'll just finish this up, turns out this was pretty easy in retrospect.
For $\gamma\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}$, let $p$ be the number of $\gamma_i=+1$, so $q=n-1-p$ is the number of $\gamma_i=-1$. Then \begin{align}b_{\gamma} = 1 + p - (n-1-p) = 2(1+p) - n = -(n-2(1+p))\tag{1}\\
\epsilon_{\gamma} = (-1)^{q} = (-1)^{n-1-p} = (-1)^{n-(1+p)}\tag{2}\end{align} Define $r = 1+p, 1\leq r\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$, then $b_{\gamma}=-(n-2r)$ and $\epsilon_{\gamma} = (-1)^{n-r}$. The number of $\gamma$ such that the number of $\gamma_i = +1$ is $p$ is simply $$\binom{n-1}{p} = \binom{n-1}{r-1}\tag{3}.$$ So now let's sum of $p$ (or $r$) using :

\begin{align}
\sum_{\gamma\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1},b_{\gamma}<0} \epsilon_{\gamma}b_{\gamma}^{n-1} &= \sum_{1\leq r\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^{n-r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}(-(n-2r))^{n-1} \\ &= \sum_{1\leq r\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^{n-r+n-1}\binom{n-1}{r-1}(n-2r)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{1\leq r\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^{r+1}\binom{n-1}{r-1}(n-2r)^{n-1}
\end{align}

Which is what we wanted.

Comment: I have not understood.

Comment: Which part in particular?

Comment: All. It is an integral question and I don't see any integral symbol in the answer.